# Normal map baking weird result

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

[image: weird normal bake]

Can somebody analyze the picture and explain what I am possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Your margin is too high. Try 2px or unwrap again with a bigger island margin

Comment: Much better result with lower Margin. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ivory addon, it actually unwraps all of the leaves over another, so you dont need to unwrap unless you aim to export the mesh.